# Rails: Couldn't find Post with 'id'=index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So in my post controller, I have

```
def index
    @post = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')
end

def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end



private
    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
    end
```

and in my .erb file

```
 <% @post.each do |post| %>
            <h2 class="post_wrapper">
                <h2 class="title"><%= link_to post.title, post %></h2>
                <p class="date"><%= post.created_at.strftime("%B, %d, %Y")</p>
        <% end %>
```

The link is supposed to be picking up the 6 in /posts/6, but I suppose it isnt.

Edit: Here is my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
     resources :posts
     root "index#index"
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To visit your `index` route, you shouldn't be going to `/posts/index` rather `/posts`.

The error is likely occurring because

GET `/posts/index` would map to `/posts/:id`, which would be calling the show action of your posts_controller.

Run `rake routes` to see the route mappings of your application

**Sidenote:** I don't think your variable nomenclature is the best. If you have a collection of objects, I think it makes sense to call them `@posts`, to avoid confusions, while a single instance could be called `@post`

Comment: Im using a youtube tutorial mostly. The guy doing it isn't the best but I understand what he is doing. Thanks for the help by the way!

Comment: It worked. I had a few inline errors that it was too late for me to notice.

I'm usually pretty good at naming my variables specifically as to what they need to be. It was just late and the girlfriend was stressing me a little bit.

Thanks for all the help. It's nice to fix these things, and its posting correctly :)

I upvoted you but it says im too newbie for it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry for the wrong answer: `<%= link_to post.title, post_path(post) %>`.

I check, and it work. This usage is not the problem. I doubt that if you keep visit `/posts/index`? If so, just don't, visit `/posts` and click the link. If it's `link_to` method that generate the wrong url, please post the html that it generate.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a great idea to explain a bit more... Don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

You called the Url wrong so it is taking '/posts/index'. Add a path to tell the action where to go, **observe the post_path(post)**

```
<% @post.each do |post| %>
    <h2 class="post_wrapper">
    <h2 class="title"><%= link_to post.title, post_path(post) %></h2>
    <p class="date"><%= post.created_at.strftime("%B, %d, %Y")</p>
<% end %>
```

Check these routes for more info, You can send an oject in place of id too, so `post_path(post)` sends you to post detail page

```
HTTPVerb    Path            Controller#Action   Named Helper
GET         /posts           posts#index        posts_path
GET         /posts/new       posts#new      new_post_path
POST        /posts           posts#create       posts_path
GET         /posts/:id       posts#show     post_path(:id)
GET         /posts/:id/edit posts#edit      edit_post_path(:id)
PATCH/PUT   /posts/:id       posts#update   post_path(:id)
DELETE      /posts/:id       posts#destroy  post_path(:id)
```

Comment: The error page is telling me that

def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
 end

Is where the error is at, I changed it to that, but it's still giving me crap. Im very new to Rails, been working with it lightly for a month so far

Comment: Add the routes.rb flie

Comment: i put it up in the question. I have 2 controllers, this is the blog controller of a full website that Im working on currently.

Comment: Do you have Index controller? Or you mean to add root to `posts#index`?
Also,  match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => :get is not necessary for the current functionality, change them and check.

Comment: I do mean to do that, the main site is in the index controller, while the "blog" (mostly a way to practice using sql with rails and outputting) is inside the posts controller

I removed the get, didn't change the error im receiving.

Comment: I've got to hit the bed for now, but I updated it. If i can't figure it out Im probably just going to scrap it and start again tomorrow...

Thanks for all the help

Comment: Did you change the form?

Comment: Turns out the actual index page had some errors, and I was going to the wrong URL. Thanks for all the help last night cleaning up code and stuff.

Was just WAY too tired to focus... Sorry